# Parse JavaScript code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, parsing

I have the following JavaScript code as a string literal:

```
var $Page = new function()
{
    var _url= 'http://www.some.url.com';

    this.Download = function()
    {
        window.location = _url;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I could get the value of the `_url` variable from my C# code? An open source library perhaps? I did this using a Regular Expression, but I was hoping for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at the open-source Javascript .NET (http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.

This sample of code should help you:

```
Javascript context = new JavascriptContext();
context.Run("var _url= 'http://www.some.url.com';") // You put your javascript in the function run
String url = (String)context.GetParameter("_url"); // You get your url from javascript
```

That's it.

Answer (score 5):

There is an open-source JavaScript interpreter in C# at http://jint.codeplex.com, if you need more than just getting the value.

This is now moved to [GITHUB](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint)

Comment: +1 for a solution that is portable on any .NET platform (I'm using Mono) and doesn't require an external executable.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the javascript function using the [DLR](http://dlr.codeplex.com/) and/or [MyJScript](http://myjscript.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a javascript parser, but parsing javascript for just that one value is probably way overkill.