# Parse JavaScript from html string in C#/Java

Tags: java, javascript, c#, html, web-scraping

I am trying to do some WebScraping of a site and the data is in dynamically loaded containers. It appears that the loading is done via JavaScript. Therefore I would need to execute it, in order to get it. I have written 2 versions of the program, one in Java and one in C#, so helping me with one would be nice enough.

I am currently using WebResponse/WebRequest in C# and HttpURLConnection in Java. I have to login into the site first, which already works like a charm. Now I need to parse the content, so the data gets filled in and the containers loaded. Is there an easy way to run the html through a browser control or an already included library?

Comment: Did you ignore all suggestions given when you wrote the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720678/parse-javascript-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have the HTML data of the website, where the javascript is not parsed yet. Normally the browser would do this job for me. But I do not know, how to do this in my program. I would either need a library which accepts a cookie for the session of the login or the html data to parse.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you could just use a hidden WebControl. With that you could execute everything you need.